# NPN_ScheldueTimer call brings firefox to crash (Mac OS X)

Tags: macos, firefox, plugins

How I use it:

> NPNetscapeFuncs* NPNFuncs;
>
> // ...
>
> timerID = NPNFuncs->scheduletimer(GetNPPInstance(), Interval, 1, Function);

At the same time, my plugin work properly both in Safari and Google Chrome.

Firefox version: 3.6.9

Mac OS X version: 10.6.4

Crash report: http://crash-stats.mozilla.com/report/index/d1b471c6-4a03-4536-8177-c50e02100914

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have looked through mozilla firefox 3.6.9 sources and discovered neither **mozilla-1.9.2/modules/plugin/base/public/npapi.h** nor **mozilla-1.9.2/embedding/browser/activex/src/pluginhostctrl/pluginsdk_include/npapi.h** doesn't contain this function.

Also I have discovered these two files has different NP_VERSION_MINOR values. Public header assigns 22, but embedded assigns 11. Is it a bug?

Firefox 4.0b6 supports this function and assigns 25 to NP_VERSION_MINOR in **/modules/plugin/base/public/npapi.h**. Activex version is 11.